# auth.test method doesn't work when creating Slack App

Tags: typescript, slack, slack-api, slack-bolt

While creating an slack app using Bolt, having trouble with the following code defined in the slack api, which is not working properly.
`await client.auth.test(token);`
Specifically, the token is determined to be valid even though the token is undefined.
We develop using typescript.

We have tried the following items.

1. Hardcoded "undefined" as a method argument as follows.
   `await client.auth.test(undefined);`
   Despite the fact that the token is not valid, the results in our development environment were 　　valid.
   Furthermore, we tried a similar token(actually, tried "undefined") using the tester for the method listed in the api document below, and it returned invalid results as expected.
   [a doc of auth.test](https://api.slack.com/methods/auth.test)
2. We tried to modernize the package, but did not see any change in the results.
   We are still using the latest version(=3.13.2) of the @slack/bolt.

Since the value of token is printed just before the auth.test method, the argument must surely be "undefined".
We also considered the possibility of version dependencies between packages being broken, but since we used the `npm install @slack/bolt` commands to install @slack/bolt, we think this is unlikely.

The following versions of @slack related packages are used.
+-- @slack/bolt@3.13.2
+-- @slack/oauth@2.5.2

If anyone has been in the same situation or knows of a solution, please let us know.